# Can I get Apache2 requests pre second without using mod_status or watching log files

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there a way to get Apache2 requests per second or stats similar to what mod_status outputs without having to install mod_status or watch log files.

Comment: You can parse the `access.log` which contains a timestamp of the request.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I don't want to have to interact with the log files.

Comment: Parsing logs is by far the easiest. Another option.. use libpcap/ngrep and parse the network traffic. You should be even more specific. Why no log parsing, why no modstatus. You could also try to setup iptables to count. Or use a reverse proxy and let it count. In the end, it all ends up with log parsing.

Comment: Agreed with @DanFromGermany. You need to specify the **why** here, as it will greatly help us give you a helpful answer.

Comment: I was hoping there was a tool/method I could use to get the stats on the command line without having to get them via HTTP as I would only ever need to access them from a shell on the localhost. 

I know I can obtain the solution I am after parsing log files and using mod_status. My questions specifically is there a way to get this information without using these methods. The *why* is purely because I find these solutions to be in-elegant.

Comment: You can build a wrapper that parses logs or mod_status page in the console... like `./apache-stats` and it prints the output. Be creative ;-)

Comment: I don't see anything "in-elegant" about using mod_status. I do what @DanFromGermany suggested all the time and accessing it via http is useful when you're running a cluster as you can just put it inside a loop and see all the info you need for the entire cluster. I also don't see what's wrong with parsing the log files.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I appreciate the suggestions. I have used mod_status for years, and I am aware of what I can do with logs. There is nothing wrong with these solutions, they're great. My specific question (which it seems that the answer to is a simple "no") was about being able to achieve the same results without using the methods you are suggesting. I was setting up mod_status and my thought process was, "hmm, it's weird that I have to do an HTTP get to get these stats, surely someone has come up with a tool that doesn't require that." Hence my question.